# LINQ Cast throws exception going from decimal to double

Tags: linq, exception, .net-core, casting

Using .NET Core 3.0, casting from decimal to double throws an `InvalidCastException`:

```
var list = new List<decimal> { 1.00001m };
var dlist = list.Cast<double>().ToList();
```

But this is a work-around:

```
var list = new List<decimal> { 1.00001m };
var dlist = list.Select(v => (double)v).ToList();
```

The code at [corefx/Cast.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/fe969a5893b845c0ba4550d828894c49745f456f/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Cast.cs) seems to show a regular ol' cast being done:

```
yield return (TResult)obj!;
```

Thoughts on why the work-around is needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your workaround is doing a run-time conversion; un-boxing and casting. However, what you are trying to do is to cast a boxed value. This is not supported by the cast operator. To learn more about the limitations of Cast<>() and how it relates to boxed/un-boxed value casting please see the following link: [Representation and Identity by Eric Lippert](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity/)